# Is there a way to detect when iframe started loading not finished?

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I am aware that it is possible to detect load event with jQuery:

```
$('#iframeid').load(function(){
    alert('frame has (re)loaded');
});
```

Is it possible to detect when it's started loading **on different origin** instead of finishing load ?

Answer (score 0):

You can by using MutationObserver https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn254985(v=vs.85).aspx. But this is supported only by newer versions of browsers, you can find here the full list http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver

Usage:

```
<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>

var iframe = $("body").find("#iframe");
var observerConfig = {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    characterData: true
};
var iframeObserver = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {

    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
             if (mutation.attributeName == "src"){
            // your code
       }
    });
});

iframeObserver.observe(iframe[0], observerConfig);
// later, you can stop observing
//observer.disconnect();

setTimeout(function () {
    iframe.attr("src", "test");
}, 2000);
```

Here is the full fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/jrmbzdp9/2/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but once the survey filled and clicked on send it does not captures the event. Am I missing something here ? https://jsfiddle.net/jrmbzdp9/28/

Comment: This will work only if you change the src of the iframe(basically loading it with something else), i changed the fiddle to set the src with jquery instead of giving it in the tag https://jsfiddle.net/jrmbzdp9/29/, if this is not good enough for you, i have no other ideea how you can achieve this